# How can I include adaptive parallel payments to my project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, parallel-processing, payment

Can anyone tell me about adaptive parallel payments? How can I include it in my project?  I am already able to integrate simple payment sender to receiver but I want to try it with multiple receivers.

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive Payments has been deprecated since December of 2017, and no new integrations are supported.

There is [multi-seller payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/platforms/checkout/configure-payments/multiseller-payments/) , but I don't know if it works without being a PayPal partner. You can try it.